# Shortcut to select a file path text object

Tags: vim

With vim text-objects I can copy some text like  `vib` or `vi"`. See `:help object-select`

I would be happy to have a similar shortcut for selecting a file path like "/my/path/to/file". In functions like `gf` or `^xf` some kind of matching is done, but I could not find a matching shortcut.

Any ideas how to make a shortcuts like `vif`, `yif` or `dif` to work? Or any plugin suggestions?

Comment: You are talking about text-objects, not motions.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I edited the question. Seems, that I had too much motions in my mind to solve the problem at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a text object called "file" quickly if [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) is installed.

```
call textobj#user#plugin('file', {
      \ 'file': {
      \ 'pattern': '\f\+', 'select': ['af', 'if']
      \ }
      \ })
```

Thus `vif`, `yif`, etc. would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy to do with my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130):

```
:call CountJump#TextObject#MakeWithCountSearch('', 'f', 'a', 'v', '\f\@<!\f', '\f\f\@!')
```

This creates an `af` text object, based on the `'isfname'` setting (`\f` regexp atom).